# Vector of QAction not compiling

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a vector of `QAction` objects and I wrote the following code:

```
std::vector<QAction> test;
for (quint16 tt = 0; tt < 5; tt++)
{
   test.push_back(QAction(this));
}
```

Compiling this shows me the error:

> error C2248: 'QAction::QAction' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QAction'

But if I create a `QAction` object like this, it works fine:

```
QAction test2(this);
```

Can anyone please point out the mistake in my code?

Comment: Why a `std::vector`?

Comment: @StoryTeller maybe because its terribly verbose syntax compared to Qt containers ;) I'd have to second that, if you are already using Qt, you might as well use its containers too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QAction` inherits `QObject` and as such is not copyable. The copy constructor that is needed for `std::vector` is private and inaccessible.

The second scenario works because there is no copying involved.

Use `std::vector<QAction *>` and `new QAction(this)` instead. Or you can use `QList<QAction>` which will work, because internally it will implicitly use pointers.

Comment: Why recommend raw owning pointers over `std::unique_ptr<QAction>`?

Comment: Because for Qt it is a non-issue. The objects will be collected anyway.

Comment: You are right. I hate that Qt changes the memory handling of the language.

Comment: Qt isn't changing anything. It just implemented some basic stuff that C++ lacked for an inexcusably long time. And it is understandable that Qt's developers aren't going back and changing everything just because C++ finally bothered to add in improvements :) Maybe it will be utilized in Qt 6, but you don't change that kind of horse mid-race, not without breaking stuff, and Qt is so huge it has tons and tons of things to break.